# SEO Impact of two different systems of shopping cart under the same domain?

Tags: seo, cms, shopping-cart

I had an old shopping cart website, url is something like `www.example.com/shopsys/`.
Later I have a new one using Opencart, still using the same domain name, but the landing page is at the root, i.e. `www.example.com/`.

The sold items are somehow similar, but many of the old one are not migrated to the new one, and the new one has some new additions. The bottom line is, the type of goods sold by the company hasn't changed across these two sites.

The old shopping cart is still online, my boss said she wanted to preserve the SEO/page rank this old website has. Therefore, on every page of the old shopping cart, there is a huge banner reminding the visitor that he is in the legacy website, and clicking the banner will lead him to the landing page of the new website.

The problem is that I observed in Google Search console that most (about 60-70%) search impressions are from the old shopping cart.

For both the old and new shopping cart web, I have submitted sitemaps for both.

Should I put the old shopping cart offline, or should I just bring down the sitemap of the old shopping cart?

And any other suggestions? I am feeling that I might have been making some obvious SEO mistakes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say "shopping cart" I think you actually mean "e-commerce content management system (CMS)".   The shopping cart is the page where users can see the items they picked out before they complete checkout.    Search engines don't care about shopping carts because their bots never add anything to the cart.   You are asking about migrating products between two CMSes.

Comment: With the point you raised in mind I dug in Google and got this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_shopping_cart_software

Comment: I think it's ok to call it this way; also, I want to point out that both the new and old websites  are already up and running now, product migration is not my focus

Comment: How many items are there in the new e-commerce system?

Comment: About 800 products in the new cms

Comment: I would do 301 redirects from the old pages to the new ones. Thos wpuld transmer most if the Google Juice.